# CPack without a CMake project

Tags: linux, cmake, rpm, cpack

I'm trying to create a package using CPack but struggling to find examples or documentation that helps me for my use case where I didn't build the code using a cmake project. I have a GO project that has produced a binary that I want installed on a system via either RPM on Linux or MSI on Windows.

My folder structure is like so:

```
HelloWorld
 |
 +---bin
 |    |
 |    +---l_run_me
 |    +---w_run_me.exe
 |
 +---src
 |    |
 |    +---hello_world.go
 |
 +---helper
 |     |
 |     +---pre_in.sh
 |     +---pre_un.sh
 |     +---post_in.sh
 |     +---post_un.sh
 |     +---wix_patch.xml
 |
 +---Copyright.txt
 +---CPackConfig.cmake
```

The files chosen for the installer would depend on the OS I was building for. It all seemed quite trivial for Windows using the WiX generator. I was able to build an installer with the code listed below:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "HelloWorld")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "ABC Software")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "A long package description should go here")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "A summary description goes here")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Copyright.txt")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "0")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME})
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "HelloWorld")
SET(CPACK_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin" "/")
if(WIN32)
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR WIX)
    SET(CPACK_WIX_UPGRADE_GUID "b7cf4d8b-7479-481d-8d4a-b3db19545b43")
    SET(CPACK_WIX_PRODUCT_GUID "b0e09ef0-80bc-4b20-b7e0-98bc75bd2670")
    SET(CPACK_WIX_SIZEOF_VOID_P "4")
    SET(CPACK_WIX_PATCH_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patch.xml")
endif()
```

And running the resulting MSI installed the binary into `C:\Program Files(x86)\HelloWorld` as I expected.

Now, for linux, I add a condition like:

```
if(WIN32)
    ....
elseif(UNIX)
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR RPM)
endif
```

expecting an RPM that would install the binary into `/usr/local/HelloWorld` (as per `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` specifies) but instead I get the binary placed in `/`.

What I want to happen is for the binary to install to `/var/opt/HelloWorld/<files>` so I tried setting some more variables as per CPack documentation:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/var/opt/${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/var/opt/${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DEFAULT_LOCATION "/var/opt/${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
```

but nothing worked as I expected. I noticed that the only place I had the path `/` specified was when I set the `${CPACK_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES}`. Now, this seems to be ignored on Windows but on Linux it does seem to matter.

The questions I can't seem to find answers for:

1. Is using `${CPACK_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES}` the correct way to add items to an installer when no cmake project exist? I was slightly apprehensive about using it since my interpretation of the documentation seems to suggest this is used for **supplementary** items that are not part of the main installer.
2. What are the correct CPack/CMake variables to set in order to choose a different install location? There seem to be a few to choose from and on Windows, the `${CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}` seems to be honoured but on Linux it wasn't.